# deleteone() is not working even though all conditions seem to be satisfied

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

col.delete_one(query) is not deleting the desired object in the database.

I have tried printing. It tries deleting , but it does not get deleted. I have used try and except where it prints the outcome(if it has deleted or not) and it's showing that it did not get deleted. What might be the case?

```
def del_query_one(col,q):
    try:
        col.delete_one(q)
        print("Deleted")
    except:
        print("Did not delete!")
def foo():
    query = col.find({<query condition>})
    mylist = list(query)
    if mylist:
        print("abc")
        del_query_one(col,query)
    if not mylist:
        print("xyz")
        # code for what should be done if an entry does not exist
```

Given an entry exists, it must print abc , print "deleted" then go to the second if statement and print xyz. However, it prints abc and prints "did not delete"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the query conditions to `delete_one`, not your `find` query results. So call your `del_query_one` function as:

```
del_query_one(col, <query condition>)
```

Comment: Yeah. It worked. My bad, I did not see that carefully. Thanks :)